# Codeigniter 2 and Kohana 3 tutorials?

Tags: php, codeigniter, kohana

I was wondering if anyone had any other good tutorials based on both Codeigniter 2 and Kohana 3.  I did find this tutorial on [easy authentication for codeigniter](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/easy-authentication-with-codeigniter/),  but other tutorials are from Codeigniter are version 1.7.2 and I just started learn about version 2.0.2.  I haven't found any from Kohana yet.  Any comments and help is greatly appreciated.

P.S. Yes, I have googled for tutorials, but I figured I ask here while I was looking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These two are good places to start. Sometimes the Kohana website user guide is lacking.

**Kohana beginners tutorial** - http://kowsercse.com/2011/09/04/kohana-tutorial-beginners/
**Kohana 3 unofficial wiki** -  http://kerkness.ca/kowiki/doku.php

Answer (score 1):

Really the kohana documentation you find in the download of kohana itself is going to be your best resource as far as kohana is concerned.  Also there is a kohana IRC channel where you will occasionally find good help.

```
#kohana @ irc.freenode.net
```

Answer (score 0):

Kohana 3 user guide: http://kohanaframework.org/3.1/guide/
and tutorials are here: http://kohanaframework.org/3.1/guide/kohana/tutorials

If you download the Kohana 3 package and run it in your dev server, you can enable "userguide" module in `application/bootstrap.php` (somewhere around line #100) and have it available locally.